# is there any way that you sync only files which are present in aws s3 bucket not the deleted one?

Tags: amazon-s3, sh

I am working on a project and I need to follow the steps below:

1. syncing all the files that are present in a directory to an AWS S3 bucket.
2. reading the files.

I have a shell script that contains the lines below:

```
s3 sync s3://<bucket_name>/performance/input scripts/input --region <region_name>

input_files=`ls -ltr scripts/input/ | awk -F ' ' '{print $9}'

echo ${input_files}
```

I have created Jenkins jobs under Build section. I am running the shell script above using the `docker run` command.

Now the problem is when I am trying to sync from the bucket, the files which are present in bucket are coming along with the deleted files that I have manually deleted from the bucket.

I want only the files that are present in the bucket. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

The output of the command `echo ${input_files}` is below:

```
+ input_files=

    <file_name>_2115.csv
    <file_name>_0001.csv
    <file_name>_0002.csv
    <file_name>_0003.csv
    <file_name>_0004.csv
    <file_name>_5444.csv
    <file_name>_1348.csv
    <file_name>_3914.csv
    <file_name>_5289.csv
```

This list contains files that I have manually deleted. These files end with _0001, 0002, 0003 and 0004. However, I still can see those files are coming.

Comment: See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-listing-deleted-objects/

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something i cannot see where you are syncing your s3 files too? The command works as:

`aws s3 sync <source> <destination>`

If you are syncing the files to your active directory try adding '.' as destination also your s3 source had an additional '/', should be s3:// unless your bucket somehow starts with /.

```
aws s3 sync s3://{bucket}/{key} . --region
```

Comment: my destination folder is scripts/input. I am syncing all files to scripts/input dir.

Comment: whoop sorry, completely overlooked the space. Also it doesn't look as though your actually using syncs capability more then just a copy, why not use aws s3 cp instead? Otherwise do you have versioning turned on in your s3 bucket?

Comment: what versioning does? I don't have any idea. and also how to turn it on?

Answer (score 0):

the issue was with jenkins history. 
AWS sync was working fine.
i just added one remove command from that particular dir before sync.

```
rm -rf scripts/input/*
```